# call to function jquery/ javascript

Tags: jquery

if I have a button that has onclick event like that:

```
'<a href="" class="ui-btn" onclick="call('+item.id+')">Aprobar</a>'
```

How I have to define this function call?

```
$ function call(id){

)}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need keep your function simple like this .

```
function call(id){
alert(id);

}
```

It will work for you !!

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal js function called from an inline click handler so:

```
function call(id){
    // do some stuff using id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only call the function name without `$` . i think `$` is for jquery and it dose not need for regular javascript function

```
 function call(id){
 }
```

but it is best practice to write like this

```
var call = function(id){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're declaring the function within another such as jQuery's `ready` function, you will need to scope the function in the `window` level for it to be globally available.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.call = function(id){
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in all jQuery, refer to below code.

remove onclick call and give id, like below :

```
'<a href="" id="ui-btn1" class="ui-btn">Aprobar</a>'
```

Then add onclick event using jQuery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ui-btn1").click(function(

  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(buttonId);

));

});
</script>
```

If you wan to bind click event to button by its class name then use below selector

```
 $("#ui-btn1").click(function(
```

You can select button using various selectors, please see [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).